# Digit space issue

Tags: lock-screens

I have my OPPO phone and I have used android device manager and locked my phone through it and had set 8 digit password and I want to delete password.
I have used the settings->privacy->lock screen
But it is asking for present password and it is only 4 digit's space so how can I use my 8 digit password as it does not have space?
Please suggest?

Comment: I suggest you simply boot into recovery and reset it. Make sure it has no Google account connected/set up, because it may require you to log in to the exact same account after a reset.

Answer (score 0):

it's most likely asking for the phone's security password, which is different from the screen lock code (it would exist even if you had never set a screen lock PIN or password).  If you bought the phone from a cellular provider, it'll be the last 4 digits of your phone number, unless you've changed it;  that's likely to be the case even if you bought the phone from an independent seller (if the phone was used, it's likely to be the last 4 of the previous owner's phone).

Comment: Where I live, all carriers set default SIM card security code to 1234